# Batch Convert Folder of GPX to SHP in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, batch, gpx

I have a few GPX files (up to 35 Mb, with a few tracks each one) that I want to convert to SHP. QGis is faster and easiest, than ArcGIS to convert GPX tracks to SHP, but is there a way to batch process it and keep the same file name for each new SHP?