# Generate 1 shape out of many GPX files

Tags: python, geojson, mapbox, gpx

I have many GPX files and i want to show them as layer on mapbox tiles.
I managed to create "simple polyline" from gpx and then build GeoJson which include many features.
That GeoJson is pretty big, many trips are contain with each other.
Is there an efficient way to create one shape out of many GPX files ?

Comment: Maybe not this is exactly what you're looking for and it is a qgis solution but maybe it helps a little bit: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159360/how-to-bulk-import-gpx-files-to-qgis-and-merge-into-a-single-shapefile

Comment: @Skye the answers given in your link are based on GDAL and work even without QGIS!

Comment: maybe this tool will help you: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 1):

[Adding GPX files into Arcmap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16402) gives some explanation on how to convert gpx to shp, but in arcmap.

And [Batch Convert Folder of GPX to SHP in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164699) gives a method to do it in qgis.